# Show that $\mathbb{E}[h(x)^{2}-2h(x)y+y^{2}]=\mathbb{E}[h(x)^{2}-2h(x)\mathbb{E}[y|x]+\mathbb{E}[y^{2}|x]]$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $\mathcal{D}$ be a distribution over $Z=X\times Y$. I am trying to understand the following:

Why $\mathbb{E}_{(x,y)\sim\mathcal{D}}[h(x)^{2}-2h(x)y+y^{2}]=\mathbb{E}_{x\sim\mathcal{D}_{x}}[h(x)^{2}-2h(x)\mathbb{E}[y|x]+\mathbb{E}[y^{2}|x]]$  s.t  $\mathcal{D}_{x}$ is the marginal distribution over x?

What is the connection between the destribution $\mathcal{D}$ and the margial distribution $\mathcal{D}_x$? How can we just "switch" between distributions?

Comment: These $\mathbb{E}_{(x,y)\sim\mathcal{D}}$ and $\mathbb{E}_{x\sim\mathcal{D}_{x}}$ notations must be some of the most unnecessary and confusing ones in mathematics as a whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 
\begin{align}
&\mathsf{E}_{(x,y)\sim \mathcal{D}}[h(x)^2-2h(x)y+y^2] \\
&=\mathsf{E}_{(x)\sim \mathcal{D}_x}\mathsf{E}_{y\lvert x \sim \mathcal{D}_{y|x}}[h(x)^2-2h(x)y+y^2] \\
&=\mathsf{E}_{(x)\sim \mathcal{D}_x} \left(\mathsf{E}_{y\lvert x \sim \mathcal{D}_{y|x}}(h(x)^2-2h(x)\mathsf{E}_{y\lvert x \sim \mathcal{D}_{y|x}}(y)+\mathsf{E}_{y\lvert x \sim \mathcal{D}_{y|x}}(y^2)]\right) \\
&=\mathsf{E}_{(x)\sim \mathcal{D}_x} \left(h(x)^2-2h(x)\mathsf{E}(y\lvert x) +\mathsf{E}(y^2\lvert x)\right) \\
\end{align}

Comment: Shahid, thank you. Could you please elaborate about the first and second transitions?

Comment: The first transition is simply decomposition of joint distribution, say $P_{XY}=P_XP_{Y|X}$, which follows by definition of conditional distribution. The second one follows since conditional expectation is linear operator.

Comment: Thank you, but about the first transition, how from PXY=PXPY|X we conclude this "expectation inside expectation" expression?